# How to see if gatsby-plugin-offline is working

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, offline, gatsby

I am new to Gatsby so please bear with me.

I want to add offline support to my app such that if a user were to try access it while offline (after having visited it online) it would still show up.

Would `gatsby-plugin-offline` help me achieve this?

If so, how can I try this out? So far I have tried using the plug-in in my app (all default settings), building the app and then serving it locally on my computer at `http://localhost:9000/`. When I stop the dev server and try access `http://localhost:9000/`, it does not show up. How can I test to see if this plugin works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `gatsby build` the public folder should include `sw.js` file.

Otherwise, you can find whether the service worker is registered on not at ***Chrome Dev Console*** over `Application > Service Workers`.